# Codeigniter admin users dashboard issue

Tags: php, codeigniter

Actually, i'm working on Codeigniter admin dashboard users module,i'm trying to show (dashboard) how many users is there from user table from database [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tmWGJ.png)

model file code:

```
function usercount_total($userId)
{
  $this->db->select('count(1)');
  $this->db->from('tbl_users');
  $query = $this->db->get();
  return $query->result();
}
```

controller file:

```
$res['total_users'] = $this->user_model->usercount_total($userId);
$this->loadViews("dashboard", $this->global, $res, NULL);
```

view file:dashboard.php

```
<div class="inner">
  <!-- <h3>44</h3> -->
  <h3><?php echo $total_users; ?></h3>
  <p>New User</p>
</div>
```

Comment: why is there `$userId` in `usercount_total()` method

Comment: What code you write in loadViews function?

Comment: this is load view function : $this->loadViews("dashboard", $this->global, $res, NULL);

Comment: you should use `$this->load->view('dashboard',$res);` instead of `$this->loadViews("dashboard", $this->global, $res, NULL);`

Comment: Hi pradeep, i load this only  $this->load->view('dashboard',$res);  please can you see my view code:<div class="inner">
                  <!-- <h3>44</h3> -->
                  <h3><?php echo $res;?></h3>
                  <p>New User</p>
                </div>

Answer (score 0):

Use $this

```
function usercount_total($userId)
{
 $this->db->select('count(*)');
 $this->db->from('tbl_users');
 $query = $this->db->get();
 return $query->num_rows();
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your ans, please i want to show total users in my dashboard please refer my images.

Comment: Try with `$this->db->select('count(*)');` instead.

Answer (score 0):

**You can do it with the help of `helpers`** (an alternative)

Add a file name `custom_helper.php` in `helpers` folder and load it with the help of `autoload.php` like this;

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('custom');
```

In `custom_helper.php` add a method called `users_count()` like this :

```
function users_count()
{
     $ci = & get_instance();
     return $ci->db->count_all('tbl_users');         
}
```

In view do like this :

```
<div class="inner">
  <h3><?php echo users_count(); ?></h3>
  <p>New User</p>
</div>
```

For more :https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html

Comment: try with the help of custom helper as given in my answer , hope this will help you

Comment: Thanks Pradeep for replaying,  for controller file code.

Comment: I created a file like custom_helper.php in this where i call this helper

Comment: you have to load your custom helper in `autoload.php` like this `$autoload['helper'] = array('custom');` just like other helpers see in my answer

Comment: after loading use the function directly in your view without use of controller and modal as in my answer

Comment: did you check my answer?